# How do I spy an exported function invocation in JavaScript using sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, sinon

Here is the actual code I am trying to mock

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'

import user from '../user'

export default combineReducers({
    user
})
```

I would like to setup a test such that:

```
describe('API Reducer', () => {
    it('calls combineReducers om modules', function() {
        const combinedReducerSpy = sinon.spy(...) // <-- UNKNOWN
        sinon.assert.calledWith(combinedReducerSpy, {user})
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't use any mock, you need to mock import then replace it with a spy.

Comment: What is the environment? Are you testing in Node or in browser? How are test files being built? Is Webpack used in tests?

Comment: I know how to do this in Python, but I am new to JavaScript. How do I mock the import then replace it with a spy? I am running test using jest inside of create react app.  The issue is, when I import the file in another file, it is executed on import.

Comment: Yes, this fact that you use Jest matters. The question is primarily specific to Jest, not Sinon. Try `jest.doMock('redux'); require('.../mycode'); let { combineReducers } = require('redux'); expect(combineReducers).toBeCalledWith(user)`. Don't forget `jest.resetModules()` in beforeEach. I expect that Jest purges module cache and allows to reimport the module, but I'm unable to confirm this.

Comment: https://github.com/sapegin/jest-cheat-sheet/blob/master/Readme.md

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post with my answer.
Thank you for the help!

[I wrote a JavaScript Unit Test today... Mock Import Time Function](https://dev.to/dev3l/i-wrote-a-javascript-unit-test-today-mock-import-time-function-1jdo)

```
// reducers.js
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import widget from './widget'
export default combineReducers({
    widget
})

// reducers.test.js
import redux from 'redux'
import widget from './widget'

describe('Use jest', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules()
    });

    test('first test', () => {
        jest.doMock('redux');

        require('./reducers');
        let {combineReducers} = require('redux');

        expect(combineReducers).toBeCalledWith({"widget": widget})
    });
});
```